# ConTeXt: SyncTeX and interactivity features (hyperlinks) not working in TeXworks pdf viewer

Tags: context

I am using ConTeXt from current TeXlive with LuaTeX backend on Win10. If I compile following MWE with:

```
context --synctex mwe.tex
```

and open the file `mwe.tex` also with displaying `mwe.pdf` in TeXworks and if I try to skip from source to pdf or vice versa, it doesnt work. Additionaly, if I try to use hyperlinks in TeXworks pdf viewer they dont "jump" the pdf view either.

Following MWE displays all options of fix that I was able to find. Is there a setting in TeXworks, that I am not aware of, to make SyncTeX and hyperlinks work in TeXworks for ConTeXt as they do for LaTeX compiled documents?

**MWE:**

```
% synctex=yes

\setupsynctex[state=start,method=min]

\setupinteraction
[state=start,
style=\normal]

\starttext

\startchapter[title=First,reference=chap:first]

\stopchapter

\page

\startchapter[title=Second]

Test reference to \in{chapter}[chap:first].

\stopchapter

\stoptext
```

I am aware of question:

[synctex not working with ConTeXt MkIV on macOS](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/499832/synctex-not-working-with-context-mkiv-on-macos)

But presented solution from there is not working for me either (well, maybe because I have OS Windows 10 and using TeXworks).

In Acrobat Viewer all hyperlinks work perfectly, so this is mostly question about author convinience while working with volumous pdf (or consisting of many files).

Comment: There was a revision in the synctex format at some point and now several producers and consumers are mutually incompatible.  This also affects ConTeXt and I remember there being discussions on the mailing list about it.  You might have to switch to a different viewer :(

Comment: One reference is here: https://mailman.ntg.nl/pipermail/ntg-context/2019/094638.html  I'll see if I find something with more details.

Comment: Another one: https://mailman.ntg.nl/pipermail/ntg-context/2018/092082.html

Comment: @HenriMenke Thak you Mr. Henke for references. I have to yet learn to search the mailing lists. However, from those references I am only getting confirmation of your first comment, that there are fundamental reasons for not having (full) suport for synctex. Said plainly: If it does work, good, if it doesnt, test another combination of editor+viewer until you find one that is working; or abandon synctex (I can live with that). Did I get that correctly? However, I still dont understand the not-jumping hyperlinks. Is that te same issue? (In MWE, if I click on "chapter 2" at page 2)